# What could this chip be?

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

[image]

I bought a cheap china tablet and it worked fine for a few weeks. Yesterday while charging and using at the same time it got warm.
I opened it and recharged the battery manually and it worked again.
But it is not accepting any change through the USB port.
Today I took a more closer look and found one IC was burned. The tablet is a BS109.

Is is possible to know what this chip could be? I'm guessing some voltage regulator, since voltage at battery +/- should be 4.x Volts and now only is 2.5 Volts.
I see only a 4 then a burned hole and a 0 and a 3 (4?03). On row 2 I guess it is year and week.
On another picture I think I see 4C03

Update. On a similar tablet I found that the chip is marked 4603

[image]

Comment: Guessing a pass FET or possibly a Vreg.

Comment: Partially reverse engineering a schematic usually helps

Comment: Please provide a picture showing more of the area around that SOT-23-5 (it may help reverse engineering or proofing assumptions). Crop the existing image to the chip itself.

Comment: I checked another tablet. The chip is marked 4603.

I think it is a voltage regulator of some kind. If I measure voltage on the 2 pins on the left (on second picture), the lower is positive and the above is negative. Without USB power it gives 3.6 Volts. The three other pins give 0 Volts when only running on battery.

If USB is plugged in, the 2 pins give 3.8V and the 3 pins below gives about 5V.

Comment: Search the obvious place for "SOT-23-5 4603" and you'll get a number of possibilities. At least two of them are buck converters, apparently with different pinouts, and another is a 2.5 ohm FET switch. You'll have to do some legwork and testing (e.g. which pins are connected to GND) to eliminate the wrong ones : hopefully you'll be left with one possibility, and hopefully that one will work.

Comment: I think I found it. WS4603. Same marking as mine. https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/WS4603/1112876/1&ved=0ahUKEwiewq6z9OXVAhWjYZoKHbmMD1I4ChAWCCkwAw&usg=AFQjCNH5cwfCFio2Emym2DRRmQCa_x3T7w

Comment: As a chip it's fried ... :)

Comment: Yeah, sure is... hopefully nothing else is fried... I think 9v got into the usb. The charge is a normal  cellphone charge but it can also fastcharge and I think the cable shorted.. Anyway, ws4603 from Will semiconductors Ltd is probably the one. How to get one of these is the next question or how to replace it with something else...

Comment: I have now changed the old chip with a new SY6280AAC... It was a lie to say it was easy. The old chip was soldered on a major grounds plan and all heat from the air gun was absorbed, and with the solder iron, lead melted, but hardened immediately. But eventually, after a lot of work, it came off.

With the new chip in place, the tablet is charging again, but extremely slow. it took 12 hours to fully charge a 5000mAh battery.
Well, at least it is charging, and the fix just cost me 1.42 USD

Answer (score 2):

After digging I found that it is probably a WS4603 from Will Semiconductors Ltd. This chip is hard to find. I will try and replace it with a SY6280AAC

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some more info on the chips?

Comment: The one I think is was: http://www.chinesechip.com/files/2015-06/69a83200-a698-45ca-811e-f5ac94879eda.pdf

Maybe I can use this instead: http://www.datasheet4u.com/datasheet-pdf/Silergy/SY6280/pdf.php?id=790556